# Java 7 update21 security pop ups

Tags: security, applet, java-7, signed-applet

I am running java7 update21 and getting issues with my applets. I checked with oracle docs about java7 update21. There I got to know about refraining the use of unsigned applets and introduction of new security pop up,which prompts for either block or unblock the code, in Java7 update21. I don't want to see this prompt while running my applets. The workaround from the user perspective is check the "Enable-hide warning and run with protections". I want to block this with default java control panel settings.I want to block this prompt from code.I tried by adding manifest attribute Trusted-only as true as given in Oracle docs. My application is misbehaving after adding this attribute. Is there anyother approach i should proceed with?

Comment: In what way is your app misbehaving? perhaps you could add some more detail. My understanding is that trusted-only and trusted-library are only for signed applets. Are you (self)signing your applet?

Comment: yes i am signing my applets. My application is misbehaving in the sense of functionality. There are few unsigned applets also,which i cannot sign. and i think these unsigned applets are the ones which are misbehaving after setting the True-Only attribute.

Comment: Sorry for taking a while... you may want to use the trusted-library attribute instead of the trusted-only attribute. As the name implies trusted-only will only load signed libraries/applets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution to my case. I was using self signed jars, also there were some third party self signed jars. And there was some Mixed code involved.
So according to [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u21-relnotes-1932873.html) of **java 7 update 21** i need to add the the **Trusted-Library: true** attribute to manifest of each jar used by applet.

After adding the attribute to manifest of all the jars (My own jar and third party jars) the Java loads all the classes in a separate class loader. so now the applet has access to all the classes it needs (third party ones). so now the applet loads without a prompt.